# how to compare 2 overlapping ranges without any repetition

Tags: perl

I am trying to compare values of range from @arr3 with values of range from @arr4 but I am not getting the desired output. Please suggest me the modifications in the following code to get the output as `3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15` (without repeating the values example 5 and 10) and total matched=11.

File 1: result

```
3..7
9..12
14..17
```

File 2: annotation

```
1..5   
5..10
10..15
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open ($inp1,"<result") or die "not found";
open ($inp2,"<annotation") or die "not found";
my @arr3=<$inp1>; 
my @arr4=<$inp2>;
foreach my $line1 (@arr4) {
    foreach my $line2 (@arr3) {
        my ($from1,$to1)=split(/\.\./,$line1);
            my ($from2,$to2)=split(/\.\./,$line2);
    #print $from1;print "\n";

    for (my $i=$from1;$i<=$to1 ;$i++) {
        for (my $j=$from2;$j<=$to2 ;$j++) {
            if ($i==$j) {
                print "$i";`enter code here`print "\n";
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: See [Inversion Lists](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=908453).

Comment: What was wrong with the answers you got from your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are not too large, you can use a hash, which is the best way how to achieve "without repeating" in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @result = ('3..4', '9..12', '14..17');
my @annotation = ('1..5', '5..10', '10..15');

my %cmp;
my $pass = 1;
for my $range (@result, undef, @annotation) {

    $pass = 2, next unless $range;

    my ($from, $to) = split /\Q../, $range;
    for my $num ($from .. $to) {
        $cmp{$num} = $pass if 1 == $pass or $cmp{$num};
    }
}

my @output = sort { $a <=> $b } grep 2 == $cmp{$_}, keys %cmp;
print join(',', @output), "\nTotal matched: ", scalar @output, "\n";
```

Comment: Fails on repeated input in one file that is not matched in the other:

    my \@result     = ('9..12', '14..17');
    my \@annotation = ('1..5', '5..10', '10..15');

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    open ($inp1,"<result") or die "not found";
    open ($inp2,"<annotation") or die "not found";
    my @arr3=<$inp1>;
    my @arr4=<$inp2>;
    foreach my $line1 (@arr4) {
            foreach my $line2 (@arr3) {
                    my ($from1,$to1)=split(/\.\./,$line1);
                    my ($from2,$to2)=split(/\.\./,$line2);
                    for (my $i=$from1;$i<=$to1 ;$i++) {
                            for (my $j=$from2;$j<=$to2 ;$j++) {
                                    $res = grep(/$i/, @result);
                                    if ($i==$j && $res == 0) {
                                            print "$i enter code here\n";
                                            push(@result, $i);
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: i have 1 more array arr2=(4,5,2) now i want to print $i value only if the element of arr2 > 3. your above code is giving output-3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15 but after implementing this new condition, it should give output as 3,4,5,6,7,9,10. i am not getting where to implement the condition, i had tried but it is not giving the desired result. @ProfGhost